# Rspec testing results of instance_eval

Tags: ruby, rspec, metaprogramming

So I'm writing a method which will result in adding some code to a class (Taking a hash of options and creating a arel-style `default_scope`, specifically). While I've played around with simply doing MyClass.send to get the code to the class, I feel an `instance_eval` will read cleaner and be more clear.

```
# test
let(:hash) { {order: "my_column desc"} }
let(:arel) { Proc.new{ order(hash[:order]) } }
it "converts options hash to arel calls" do
  MyClass.send(:my_translator_method, hash)
end

# method
def self.my_translator_method(hash)
  code = method_to_convert_options_to_arel
  self.instance_eval <<CODE
    default_scope #{code}
  CODE
end
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to hook into the class in order to determine that it was changed in the way expected.

Answer (score 1):

First, why can't you do something like :

```
self.send(:default_scope, code)
```

instead of using metaprogramming ?

Second, you should always test behavior, not implementation :

```
correct_ordered_elements = [.....]
Myclass.all.should == correct_ordered_elements
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

```
it "converts options hash to arel calls" do
  expect { MyClass.default_scope }.to raise_error
  MyClass.my_translator_method hash
  expect { MyClass.default_scope }.to_not raise_error
end
```

and then, for good measure - check that the scope is correct also:

```
it "creates an ordered scope" do
  MyClass.my_translator_method hash

  expect(MyClass.default_scope.to_a).to eq MyClass.order("my_column desc").to_a
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with an expectation on the class singleton:

```
let(:code) { method_to_convert_options_to_arel }
let(:hash) { {order: "my_column desc"} }

it "sets the default scope" do
  expect(MyClass).to receive(:default_scope).with(code)
  MyClass.my_translator_method(hash)
end
```

I'd argue that you shouldn't test the scope itself here--write a separate test for the method that produces the Arel code.